# Magento hidden css file

Tags: css, file, magento, hidden

I am working on a store in Magento. I used a custom template where I altered some colors (with permission of course) but when I try to change some of the things, the old style just sticks. I run Magento locally and I tried everything from restarting MAMP to flushing cache.

When I use 'inspect element' on my browser I find that the code of my store looks like this;

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="nl" lang="nl">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Vanilla Looks - Kettingen</title>
<meta name="description" content="Default Description" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Magento, Varien, E-commerce" />
<meta name="robots" content="INDEX,FOLLOW" />
<link rel="icon" href="http://127.0.0.1:8888/skin/frontend/base/default/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://127.0.0.1:8888/skin/frontend/base/default/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var urlSkinsite='http://127.0.0.1:8888/skin/frontend/galaeva/default/';
//]]>
</script>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var BLANK_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8888/js/blank.html';
    var BLANK_IMG = 'http://127.0.0.1:8888/js/spacer.gif';
//]]>
</script>
<![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://127.0.0.1:8888/skin/frontend/galaeva/default/css/styles.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://127.0.0.1:8888/skin/frontend/galaeva/default/css/widgets.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://127.0.0.1:8888/skin/frontend/galaeva/default/slideshowwidget/css/wt-rotator.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://127.0.0.1:8888/skin/frontend/galaeva/default/css/print.css" media="print" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1:8888/js/prototype/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1:8888/js/lib/ccard.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1:8888/js/prototype/validation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1:8888/js/scriptaculous/builder.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1:8888/js/scriptaculous/effects.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1:8888/js/scriptaculous/dragdrop.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1:8888/js/scriptaculous/controls.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1:8888/js/scriptaculous/slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1:8888/js/varien/js.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1:8888/js/varien/form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1:8888/js/varien/menu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1:8888/js/mage/translate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1:8888/js/mage/cookies.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1:8888/skin/frontend/galaeva/default/js/galaeva.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1:8888/skin/frontend/base/default/slideshowwidget/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1:8888/skin/frontend/base/default/slideshowwidget/js/jquery.wt-rotator.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://127.0.0.1:8888/skin/frontend/galaeva/default/css/styles-ie.css" media="all" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1:8888/js/lib/ds-sleight.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1:8888/skin/frontend/base/default/js/ie6.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<style type="text/css">

body { 
        font: 12px/1.5 Arial, sans-serif;

        background-color:#fff;

        background-image:url(http://127.0.0.1:8888/skin/frontend/galaeva/default/images/pattern/1.png);
    }

.page { background-image:url(http://127.0.0.1:8888/skin/frontend/base/default/images/header_top.png); }


.nav-content { background-image:url(http://127.0.0.1:8888/skin/frontend/galaeva/default/images/bg_menu.png); }

a,
.product-detail-slide button.btn-cart span span, 
.product-special button.btn-cart span span, 
#tabs .ui-tabs-panel ul li button.btn-cart span span { color:#c20066; }

.block .block-title,
.latest-reviews h1,
.product-special h1,
.product-detail-slide .price-box, 
.product-special .price-box, 
#tabs .ui-tabs-panel ul li .price-box,
.cart .discount h2,
.cart .shipping h2,
.cart .totals h2 {
    background-color:#000;
}

.menu { color:$settings->get_nav_text_color(); }

/* Top level menu */
#nav a.level-top,
.menu .submenu a { 
        font:normal bold 12px/1.55 Arial,sans-serif !important; 
            color:#fff; 
    }
#nav a.level-top:hover,
.menu .submenu:hover a { color:#fff; }

/* Sub #1 menu */
#nav li li a,
.menu li.submenu div a { 
        font:normal 12px/1.55 Arial,sans-serif !important; 
            color:#bebebe !important; 
    }
#nav li li a,
.menu li.submenu  div a:hover{ color:#fff !important; }


.block .block-title strong,
.latest-reviews h1,
.product-special h1,
.cart .discount h2,
.cart .shipping h2,
.cart .totals h2 {
        font:bold 14px/31px Arial, sans-serif;

        color:#fff;
    }

.block-subscribe .block-title strong { font:12px/1.5 Arial, sans-serif !important }

.widget .widget-title h2 { font:bold 14px/31px Arial, sans-serif; }


.price,
#opc-login h3, 
#opc-billing #billing1, 
#opc-shipping #shipping1, 
#shipping_method1, 
.checkout-onepage-success h2.sub-title  {
    color:#AB0051;
}

</style>
```

I deleted the bottom part because it exceeded the body limit of Stack.
Anyway, I think the problem is in the inline style that appears on the page.

There it says;

```
.block .block-title,
.latest-reviews h1,
.product-special h1,
.product-detail-slide .price-box, 
.product-special .price-box, 
#tabs .ui-tabs-panel ul li .price-box,
.cart .discount h2,
.cart .shipping h2,
.cart .totals h2 {
    background-color:#000;
}
```

Here it says that my block-titles are still black, even though I edited them in the css file to be another color. I tried looking up this piece of css in every css file that comes with the theme but this piece of code isn't in any of the files...

I'm very puzzled now, how does magento get these pieces of css and where can I change them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The piece of code you are looking at, its coded inside the page. Its not making any call to a `.css`, thats why you wont find it in any of the `.css` files.

If you want to give preference to your `.css` styles you can try using some `!important` in the styles you want to appear. That should work!

Answer (score 0):

`.block .block-title` is defined as black in the first CSS-rule of the inline CSS. Then `.block .block-title strong` is defined as white. If you remove the reference in the first rule maybe that will help you.

The Inspect Element view in your browser should also tell you where the color comes from. I prefer Chrome and there you can see it to the right in the Elements view with a reference to file and row number.

Comment: I can't edit the inline css because it isn't in any of the files. Magento takes a lot of different files and makes them into a layout. the !important tag worked though :)